# Loading large amount of data incrementally using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, charts, highcharts

I'm going to be using a chart (probably Highstock) to display data from a database. Often there will be a large number of records retrieved (tens of thousands). I'd like the chart to start displaying the data as it's downloaded instead of having to wait for all the data to be retrieved.

I know I could do this manually by using multiple requests to the server for smaller bits of data, but this seems quite inefficient.

Is there tool or other code in Javascript that let's you process the data as it arrives using a single request to the server (some buffering is okay)?

EDIT: Although I've specifically asked about a client-only solution, if the only ones available require something on the server, I'm working in a LAMP (Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP) environment.

EDIT: Since this question was closed, I can't post an answer, but I've included the solution to the problem as a comment. Hopefully it'll be useful for others.

Comment: I'm not sure why people thought this question isn't constructive. I'm asking about a specific problem that I'm facing that I couldn't immediately find a solution for.

Comment: I will add that I have found a solution. It turns out that in Chrome and Firefox at least, XMLHttpRequest will populate responseText with partial data that can be accessed once readyState == 3 (LOADING).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what back end you'll be using to grab the data from the database, but if it's .NET you could use something like [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR) to trickle the data down from the server.

Comment: We're using LAMP. So no .NET. But thanks for the reference.